# PHP code в верху страницы сайта. [PHP, AJAX]

Tags: php, ajax

Структура:

```
<?php include "page2.php" ?>
<html>...site...</html>
```

Page2.php отправляет SQL-запрос в базу, который проверяет наличие новых уведомлений. Если они есть, то записывает в переменные, которые расскиданы по сайту, в title, header'e и footer'e.

Можно ли как-то с помощью AJAX обновлять эту страницу раз в 10 секунд, не возвращая результат, а просто обновляя переменные?

Если нет. То если какие-то другие способы динамической загрузки данных с БД на PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно с помощью Ajax отправлять запрос к скрипту, получать из него ответ и подставлять данные.

1. Надо будет переписать page2.php, чтобы он возвращал JSON массив с вашими значениями из БД. Например:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 
$data = array(
    'value'  => 'Значение'
);
 
echo json_encode($data);
```

2. На странице, где надо будет обновлять данные сделать ajax запрос.
   Например, используя jQuery:

```php
function getUpdates() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'page2.php',
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(response){
            $('.тут_класс_с_переменной_где_надо_поменять_значение').html(response.value)
      }
  });
}
setInterval(getUpdates(), 10000); // Делаем запрос каждые 10 секунд
```

Comment: Перед строкой setInterval(getUpdates(), 10000) напишите getUpdates(); Тем самым вы сделаете запрос сразу после загрузки страницы.